# How to update an repository object in uft?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I use UFT 11.53, Windows 8.1 Pro et vbscripts.
I've a question : Is it possible to add objects to an object repository automatically using VBScript?

My problem : I've an application in which I've to automate tests and qualifications. I would like to add an new object (using vbscript) to my repository object.

**Below is my code which I tried:**

```
Dim RepositoryFrom   
Dim ParentObject   

ObjectRepositoryPath="D:\repository.tsr"  

'Creating Object Repository  utility Object   
Set RepositoryFrom = CreateObject("Mercury.ObjectRepositoryUtil")   

'Load Object Repository   
RepositoryFrom.Load ObjectRepositoryPath
Set oWebElement = WebElement(""&str) 'str = "PR1500073LRBA", it's an element of my table
Set ParentObject = Browser("fia").Page("fia_3")

RepositoryFrom.AddObject oWebElement, ParentObject, "reference"

RepositoryFrom.Save

Set RepositoryFrom = nothing
Set oWebElement = nothing
Set oParent = nothing
```

**With this code, I've an message error :**
*'AddObject' - General error.

Line (63): "RepositoryFrom.AddObject oWebElement, ParentObject, "reference"".*

Do you know why I've this message ?

Thanks :)